# loop terminates program where it shouldn`t

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, do-while

i`m practicing, and for some reason selection == p terminates my program, if the vector has any content. What am i doing wrong?

I tried it both with for and while loop, and the results are the same :(

```cpp
do
{
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> selection;

    if (selection == 'p' || selection == 'P')
    {
        if (numbers.size() == 0)
        {
            cout << "[] The vector is empty" << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "[ ";
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= numbers.at(i))
            {
                cout << numbers.at(i) << ' ';
                i++;
            }
            // for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.size(); i++)
            //     cout << numbers.at(i) << ' ';
            cout << "]" << endl;
        }
    }
} while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
```

Comment: What's the type of `selection` variable? Also, I am guessing that you would want `while (i < numbers.size()` here

Comment: `std::vector::at` will throw an exception when it's outside of bounds, and you keep incrementing `i`. You should use a debugger, and step through the execution of your app.

Comment: Is it possible that `i` gets bigger than the size of the vector?

Comment: @Wander3r, selection is char type.
@Kaldrr, yes i just thought of that myself too, thank you for the reminder :) 
@user253751, it is indeed goes higher than the vector`s size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters these loops

```
while (i <= numbers.at(i))
{
    cout << numbers.at(i) << ' ';
    i++;
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.size(); i++)
```

are not equivalent.

The condition in the first loop does not make a sense.

The condition in the second loop invokes undefined behavior because the index `i` may not be equal tp `numbers.size()`.

You need to write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++ )
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    std::cout << "[ ";
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( i ) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << numbers[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << " ]\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: or rage-for loop

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right! now i see where did i do a mistake. i put:     while (i < numbers.at()) instead of numbers.size().

Apologies for the silly question and not realising it :)